# Match specific value in mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

Following is the schema of a user collection:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    supporterOf: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'individual',
        required: false
    }],
})

module.exports = Mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

I want to populate 'supporterOf' which is a collection of individual (ref: individual).
The 'supporterOf' contains an array of ObjectId.
I am having the problem of matching the specific objectId with that ObjectId array.
Can anyone suggest me how I can match specific ObjectId with an array of ObjectIds in populate function?

Comment: what do you mean by "problem of matching the specific objectId " you need to insert `individual` object id into `usermodel` then call `populate()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a reference of 'individual' in supporterOf and you want to populate only relevant object from the array of individuals?
If this is right case then do the following:

```
YourUserModel.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)
     }).populate({
        path: 'supporterOf',
        match: {
           yourObjectOfIndividualDocument: yourMatchingIdOfIndividual
        }
     })
     .exec()
```

Replace `yourObjectOfIndividualDocument: yourMatchingIdOfIndividual` by `name: 'abcd'`.
Here `name` is the field of Individual document not of User document.

Comment: It worked for me. Back then I was writing the wrong syntax for "match" key. 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is this possible ```YourUserModel.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)
     }).populate({
        path: 'supporterOf',
        match: {
           'supporterOf.someFields': 'something'
        }
     })
     .sort(sortingObject) ```?
I want to use the populated field in match query. Is this possible?
My problem is that I want to filter based on populated data and then sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You add condition in [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)

if you wanted to populate fans array based on their age, and return, at most, any 5 of them

```
.populate('fans', null, { age: { $gte: 21 }}, { limit: 5 })
```

Comment: No. When you are populating individual, consider individual as an array of ObjectId, it should populate only the  index (lets say index 3) of that array.

However, there is a populate object key called match. I am using it to compare the array index with user generated id to compare but I guess I am writing wrong syntax

Comment: oh you need to populate only specific individual?

Comment: Yes I wanted to add a condition in populate function which I could have achieved by "match" key but I wasn't able to write the right syntax for matching the two ObjectIds but the other answer on this thread worked for me. 
Though, I appreciate your help. Thanks!